# R for loop only iterates over last subarray

Tags: arrays, r

I have written a simple routine to iterate over variables, including multiple subarrays, but it seems that it only loops over the last subarray instead of all of them, one at a time.

My code is as follows:

```
K <- 2 # number of subarrays

N <- 100

Hstar <- 20

perms <- 10000

specs <- 1:N 

pop <- array(dim = c(c(perms, N), K))

haps <- as.character(1:Hstar)

probs <- rep(1/Hstar, Hstar) 

for(j in 1:perms){

for(i in 1:K){

    pop[,, 1] <- sample(haps[1:10], size = N, replace = TRUE, prob = probs[1:10])

    pop[,, 2] <- sample(haps[11:20], size = N, replace = TRUE, prob = probs[11:20])

 }

 }

HAC.mat <- array(dim = c(perms, N))

for(k in specs){

for(j in 1:perms){

    for(i in 1:K){

        ind.index <- sample(specs, size = k, replace = FALSE)

        hap.plot <- pop[j, ind.index, i]

        HAC.mat[j, k] <- length(unique(hap.plot)) 
    }
}
}
```

The issue appears to be in hap.plot, which is only populated with labels from pop[,,2] (subarray 2) instead of labels from both subarrays. I am not sure why this is the case.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think there are problems before that. First, you object `perms` is overwritten when you create the `perms` array. Also,  you dont have any objet call `pop` in the very first `for` loop.

Comment: By `perms <- array(dim = c(c(perms, N), K))`, do you mean`pop <- array(dim = c(c(perms, N), K))`? Otherwise perms is overwritten and there is no pop

Comment: Right apologies, I meant to do pop <- array(dim = (c(perms, N), K)). Now there would be a pop variable... but the issue with looping over subarrays still persists oddly.

Comment: Correction: pop <- array(dim = c(c(perms, N), K))

Comment: I guess I know where it goes wrong. The inner most loop does loop over `i=1` and `i=2`, however, `HAC.mat[j, k] <- length(unique(hap.plot))` doesn't have anything to do with `i`, so result of `i=2` overwrites result of `i=1`.

Comment: @SeanLin I see what you mean. Any idea how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need `HAC.mat` as a 3-dimension array, otherwise HAC.mat can only record `hap.plot` when `i=K`.

```
K <- 2 # number of subarrays
N <- 100
Hstar <- 20
perms <- 10000
specs <- 1:N 
pop <- array(dim = c(c(perms, N), K))
haps <- as.character(1:Hstar)
probs <- rep(1/Hstar, Hstar)
for(j in 1:perms){
    for(i in 1:K){
        # looks like j was missing in previous code.
        pop[j,, 1] <- sample(haps[1:10], size = N, replace = TRUE, prob = probs[1:10])
        # change [11:20] to [1:20] for both haps and probs.
        pop[j,, 2] <- sample(haps[1:20], size = N, replace = TRUE, prob = probs[1:20])
    }
}
HAC.mat <- array(dim = c(c(perms, N), K)) # HAC.mat as 3-dim array
for(k in specs){
    for(j in 1:perms){
        for(i in 1:K){
            ind.index <- sample(specs, size = k, replace = FALSE)
            hap.plot <- pop[j, ind.index, i]
            HAC.mat[j, k, i] <- length(unique(hap.plot)) # record i on 3rd dim
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if this works, you may want to try `perms<-10` to give a try, otherwise it takes a while.

Comment: I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: The code runs fine for perms = 10, but hac.plot still only contains labels from subarray 2, i.e., haps 11:20 instead of random values from 1:20.

Comment: Your fix is definately a step in the right direction ... but the second subarray still gets overwritten instead of randomly sampling over both subarrays after playing around with it. Eventually, I also want to make it easy to alter the proportion of 'hap' labels that are assigned to each subarray...

Comment: @JarrettPhillips I checked again, looks like we missed `j` in the first loop as well, and pop had same value `pop[, , 1]` and `pop[, , 2]`. Answers is updated, please try again.

Comment: It worked! Before I was getting the same values for each perm in the pop array. Now they're random, which is what I want. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @JarrettPhillips You are welcome, and you can accept answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: Interestingly, hap.plot is still only populated with labels from 11:20 instead of 1:20, so my original question is still not solved. However, the lurking issue of repeated values in perms is solved, so we are close it seems. I'll play around with the code some more to see if I find any workaround to avoid the code overwriting.

Comment: @JarrettPhillips So you want 1:20 for 2nd subarray? It was `[11:20]` in original code, I thought you wanted to be `[11:20]`. How about now?

Comment: I would like [1:10] in the first subarray and [11:20] in the second subarray. Then I need hap.plot to contain random character labels from both subarrays. The code prior to your most recent suggestion had only elements [11:20] in hap.plot instead [1:20]...  It might be my explanation as I am not a computer programmer by training. Let me know if more clarification is needed.

Comment: hap.plot <- sample(pop, size = N, replace = TRUE) might do the trick. I'll test it out